# Merge method not defined in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following

```
# application.rb
document   = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__)))
APP_CONFIG = document[Rails.env].merge(document['global'])

# app_config.yml
global:
  site_name_lowercase: abc

staging:
  site_domain: 192.168.33.10
  site_url: http://192.168.33.10

development:
  site_domain: abc.dev
  site_url: http://abc.dev
```

When I tried to run `rails c RAILS_ENV=staging`, I got the following:

```
/home/deployer/abc/releases/20131015193830/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/deployer/abc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /home/deployer/abc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

which points to the `merge` method in `application.rb`. I ran `rails c` in development environment, which worked fine. Everything in development environment works fine, from readin the `app_config.yml` to parsing the contents of it. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add a `puts Rails.env` into `application.rb` before you load the YAML file and see what it says?

Comment: As in `abort(Rails.env.inspect)`? It outputs `"RAILS_ENV=staging"`.

Comment: It works ok for me. Is it possible that your app_config.yml is different on your staging server?

Comment: It's the same. But if I replace `document[Rails.env].merge(document['global'])` with `document['staging'].merge(document['global'])`, there's no more error on this. I think `Rails.env` is the problem because it outputs `RAILS_ENV=staging` instead of `staging`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `bundle exec rails c staging` instead of `rails c RAILS_ENV=staging`.

Comment: Already tried `bundle exec RAILS_ENV=staging rails c`, it doesn't work.

Comment: How about `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails c`?

Comment: Actually, I think `bundle exec rails c staging` is the Rails 3 standard.

Comment: Bravo. `bundle exec rails c staging` and `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails c` works. Can you update your answer then I will mark it? Thanks!